# Create a notification UI like Facebook iPhone App

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, facebook

What is the best way to implement this sort of notification system?
(Let's say I am currently viewing a UITableViewController and I want 30 pixels from the bottom to be replaced with a nice looking notification...

Thanks

Comment: As a heads up, I've tried implementing something similar, just by adding a UIView to the main UIWindow, but this seems to disable any UIScrollView scrolling to the top when the statusbar is tapped.